# UIImageView changes its size when contentmode is Scale to fill

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView embedded inside a view. I have constraints that declare that the image view is Trailing, Leading and top spaces are 0 relative to its superview. My Button space is 20. However, when I run the app, and declare the image view content mode to be scale to fill, the 20 space from the button view becomes 0 as well, meaning it stretches itself to the superview frame, which is not desired. 
what can I do to keep it in place like defined in the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by clicking on "Clip to bounds" in the image inspector in storyboard.